# Is it possible to have a DataContract as a member of a MessageContract?

Tags: c#, wcf

Is it possible to have a `DataContract` as a member of a `MessageContract`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it works just fine. You can have any serializable types as members (either `[MessageHeader]` or `[MessageBodyMember]`) of a data contract, and a data contract is serializable by WCF.

Comment: Thank you Carlos. Visual Studio did not come up with any errors but I couldn't know how the serialization was going to be handled.